# How to fill face with NURBS curve?

Tags: nurbs-surface

I'm trying to close a NURBS shape with the <kbd>F</kbd> key. It closes the shape (the control points), but does not fill the face. The editor is set to view objects in Solid Mode and X-Ray is disabled.

[image: Process]

I'm asking this because this [youtu.be](https://youtu.be/OT2JktubPFA) video shows it's possible. Some other videos also show the same being done with NURBS curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a NURBS Surface instead of a NURBS Curve.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> > `Surface` > `Nurbs Curve`

Answer (score 0):

I noted that in the YouTube video the modeller starts with a **bezier curve**, rather than a nurbs curve, allowing him different options.

When I created a bezier curve instead of a nurbs curve, it allowed me to close the points with F key.

If you convert the curve to a mesh, you can also fill the inside face with the F key.